# Error in handling Ajax "done" and "fail"

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've come across a weird issue...

The EXPECTED behaviour is: If request is successful, page displays a simple alert (just to test if it's working). If it fails, it should show the error message in the div.

```
$(function() {
    $('.error').hide(); 
    $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')  
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: '{{ route("admin.categories.store") }}'
        })
            .done(function(data) {
                $('.error').hide();
                alert(data.message.name); //simple alert just to check if it works
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR) {
                errorMessage = jqXHR.responseText;
                $('.error').text(errorMessage . "<br>"); // not sure why this line is making the DONE part stop working.
                $('.error').show();
            }); 


    });
  });
```

If I make it fail, it works, but in a success scenario, it only returns to me the raw json:

> {"message":{"_token":"lkqlTHGPQBWEVIAQvO8pWs8ORAsSifGyR2TDBEPo","name":"test","submit":"Create
>   Category"}}

I've noticed if I remove the `$('.error').text(errorMessage . "<br>");` part, the error goes away and the "success" scenario works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
$('.error').text(errorMessage . "<br>");
```

To

```
$('.error').text(errorMessage + "<br>");
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I did this. The whole php, js mix is getting to me it seems!  thank you!